# flask-login never logs out

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am doing some tests with flask-login. I am following exactly the example at

https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

everything is working fine, i manage to log in correctly and i am able to access the routes protected by the @login_required decorator.

I can log out if I explicitly do it (going to the '/logout' route) and after i do i'm no longer able to access the protected routes.

The only problem is: i never get logged out if i close the browser. In the official guide it says

> By default, when the user closes their browser the Flask Session is deleted and the user is logged out.

but this never seems to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK i've finally find a solution:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    flask.session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)
    flask.session.modified = True
```

setting flask.session.permanent to True forces flask to expire after a certain amount of time, and not when the browser is closed (which is the default behavior).

flask.session.modified = True resets the time. since this is called every request the user does, you are sure that he is going to be logged out after 20minutes of true inactivity.